# jQuery event attached to one element sharing the same class

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to find a good way to attach an event to a specific element of the DOM. This element shares the same class than others (real case: generating 20 divs by looping through a DB for example).

In order to make it as simple as possible, I created a JSfiddle available here:
[jsfiddle.net/1a27t3u4/](http://jsfiddle.net/1a27t3u4/)

the event is simple and just adds a class to the specific div:

```js
$('.bouton').click( function(){
  $('.mother').addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.mother
{
 width: 400px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border: 2px solid red;
 text-align: center;
}

.red
{
     background: red;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML:
    

    <div class="mother">
     <button class="bouton"> Click me! </button>
    </div> 
    <div class="mother">
     <button class="bouton"> Click me! </button>
    </div> 
    <div class="mother">
     <button class="bouton"> Click me! </button>
    </div> 
    <div class="mother">
     <button class="bouton"> Click me! </button>
    </div> 
    <div class="mother">
     <button class="bouton"> Click me! </button>
    </div>
```

Basically, all I want to know is how I can color the div containing the button I clicked and not all the divs by using *class* tags and not *id* tags.

I've tried adding `stopPropagation()` or `return false` at the end of the script without any success :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of targeting all the elements with the class of `.mother`, use the keyword `this` to refer to the element being clicked on, and select its parent with `.parent()`:

```
$('.bouton').click( function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('red');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1a27t3u4/1/)**

Comment: This definitely works, but is not very robust.  If the html is any more complex than the example the OP posted, this may fail.  For example, if the button is placed inside a `form` or `table` within the div with class `.mother`, the class `.red` will be applied to that element rather than the desired div.

Comment: @Vince I'm basing my reply on what the OP posted, not an infinite amount of possible variations.

Comment: Understood.  Just adding my 2 cents.  I don't think it's unreasonable to suppose that the OP may have simplified their markup for the purpose of getting help.  That being said, your solution is probably more performant than using `.closest()` if the html will be structured the way the OP posted.

Comment: @Vince and j08691: I did simplify the code. Vince is right, the button is actually part of a form and the event is "on submit". The idea is once you submitted the form, the specific div that includes the button disappears. I'll try what it does on my code and will get back to you if any problem! That is anyway a good and useful answer :)

Comment: @Lio_69 - Are you doing anything to stop the normal submission of the form which would either reload the page or redirect to a new page?

Comment: @j08691 - I do use preventDefault() when submitting the form. I tested your answer and worked fine when using the click event. I used the parents() method because the button is far away from the div that has to disappear. I'll try it when submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function:

```
$('.bouton').click( function(){
    $(this).closest('.mother').addClass('red');
});
```

This will search up the DOM and find the closest element that matches the given selector.  See the working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/1a27t3u4/3/